# How to show all MIN of SUM(column) that has the same min value?

Tags: mysql

I've been trying to get MIN of SUM of a column by doing subqueries, however in a case where I have two same SUM values, my query only returns me one of them. Is there a way to get all of them to be shown?

So for example this table is called quantity,

```
    date    product_id quantity_start quantity_end
  1/1/2020      1             10              5
  1/1/2020      2             10              5
  1/1/2020      3             12              1
  2/2/2020      1             10              5
  2/2/2020      2             11              6
  2/2/2020      3             14              1
```

my query would be

```
SELECT product_id, MIN(Total) as Minimum
FROM (SELECT product_id, SUM(quantity_start - quantity_end) as Total
      FROM quantity
      GROUP BY product_id)T
```

But this will return me only one min value while there are two since both product 1 and 2 will have total of 10 from my subquery. Is there a way to write it such that it shows me both ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are correctly grouping by your sub query, but the outer query also needs a group by so:

```
SELECT product_id, MIN(Total) as Minimum
FROM (SELECT product_id, SUM(quantity_start - quantity_end) as Total
      FROM quantity
      GROUP BY product_id)T
GROUP BY product_id;
```

See it working here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/97d7724/1